# Can 'map' and 'reduce' be implemented in Go with generics

Tags: go, functional-programming

I decided that now that generics have been introduced into Go that something like `map/reduce` should be possible. So, I took a naive stab at it and I get the error:
`./prog.go:18:36: cannot use thing (variable of type int) as type I in argument to mapper`

Which doesn't explain if the problem is fundamental or I am simply doing something wrong syntactically. Can generic map/reduce be implemented in Go?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    things := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    results := Map(things, func(t int) int {
        return t + 1
    })
    fmt.Printf("%v", results)
}

func Map[I interface{}, O interface{}](things []I, mapper func(thing I) O) []O {
    results := make([]O, 0, len(things))
    for thing := range things {
        results = append(results, mapper(thing))
    }
    return results
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done quite easily. You have an error in your code, though right here:

```
for thing := range things {
```

You are iterating over the index values (int), not the values of type `I`. You're also specifying 2 constraints (types `I` and `O`) both set to be `interface{}`. You can just use `any` instead (it's shorthand for `interface{}`)

So simply write:

```
func Map[T any, O any](things []T, mapper func(thing T) O) []O {
    result := make([]O, 0, len(things))
    for _, thing := range things {
        result = append(result, mapper(thing))
    }
    return result
}
```

## [Demo](https://go.dev/play/p/mLAgFu5sI6e)

---

This is quite closely related to some code I reviewed on codereview exchange [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275391/suggestions-for-improvement-for-generic-array-and-map-functions-in-go-1-18/276128#276128). After going through the code, and writing snippets with a ton of suggestions, I decided to just create a package and throw it up on github instead. You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/EVODelavega/smap).

In it, there's some examples that may come in handy, or help you work through some other quirks WRT generics in golang.  I wsa specifically thinking about this bit, where you can filter a generic map type using callbacks like so:

```
// given the sMap type
type sMap[K comparable, V any] struct {
    mu *sync.RWMutex
    m  map[K]V
}

// Filter returns a map containing the elements that matched the filter callback argument
func (s *sMap[K, V]) Filter(cb func(K, V) bool) map[K]V {
    s.mu.RLock()
    defer s.mu.RUnlock()
    ret := make(map[K]V, len(s.m))
    for k, v := range s.m {
        if cb(k, v) {
            ret[k] = v
        }
    }
    return ret
}
```

Comment: Interesting - are you thinking this repo should be developed with useful stuff like Map/reduce?

Comment: I feel silly for having missed this. Thanks

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno That repo was just something I threw together in response to the linked code review bit. I didn't really spend all that much time on it. At some point I started implementing a vector type but got bored (and had to get back to work on my actually job lol). I put it up on github in case someone found it useful. If they want to add functionality to it, they're more than welcome to fork/PR changes

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect use of `range`. A single variable extracted from `range` will be the index (type `int`), not the value (type `I`, which is only coincidentally `int` in this case).

Try

```golang
for _, thing := range things{...}
```